# Carles Proxy Not working in Android

Tags: android, http, ssl, https, proxy

What i do.
1-Install charles proxy in windows
2-Go to lan settings and disable use of proxy, if it was checked i have no internet connection in my laptob
3-Check my ip=192.168.1.51
4-Default charlesproxy port=8888 changed to 8886, with both dosnt work either.
5-Open Charles Proxy
6-My laptob connected with ethernet cable to switch and my android phone by wi-fi with manual proxxy settings. IP=192.168.1.51 port=8888 first and 8886 second.

I go to navigate and i have no internet connection in google chrome in android but i do have whatsapp connection for example.

Also it dosnt prompt any message thath X device is connecting to CharlesProxy so... any possible solution? Open ports?

Any solution?